# How to update delivery quantity via BAPI?

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp

In my business scenario the WMS system post GI of deliveries and send the info to SAP.

- If WMS post GI for the entire quantity ==> no problem
- If WMS post GI for quantity < delivery quantity ==> problem.
- I should update the delivery quantity (LIPS-LFIMG) and then post the GI.
- I tried with WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE and with BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CHANGE without success.

Have you ever faced this case?

Comment: did you set UPDATE_PICKING in WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE? Depending on how your picking process is set up, you either need to provide SPACE or 'X' for UPDATE_PICKING if you want to change quantities. And COMMIT has to be 'X' too, if you want the changes to be committed to the database.

Comment: Hi Dirk, my problem is not in the picking (LIPS-PKIMG) but in the delivered quantity (LIPS-LFIMG).

Comment: IIRC WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE and WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE2 are really nice modules, but not officially released by SAP for usage .This was the case , at least 4 years ago. Their intention is quite nice, but I think, the implementation is not complete/buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by calling BAPI_OUTB_DELIVERY_CHANGE
with the following mapping:

```
LS_HEADER_DATA-DELIV_NUMB = <FS_LIPS>-VBELN.
LS_HEADER_CONTROL-DELIV_NUMB = <FS_LIPS>-VBELN.
LV_DELIVERY = <FS_LIPS>-VBELN.
LS_ITEM_DATA-DELIV_NUMB = <FS_LIPS>-VBELN.
LS_ITEM_DATA-DELIV_ITEM = <FS_LIPS>-POSNR.
LS_ITEM_DATA-MATERIAL = <FS_LIPS>-MATNR.
LS_ITEM_DATA-BATCH = <FS_LIPS>-CHARG.
LS_ITEM_DATA-DLV_QTY = LS_VBPOK_TAB-PIKMG. ==> new quantity
LS_ITEM_DATA-DLV_QTY_IMUNIT = LS_VBPOK_TAB-PIKMG. ==> new quantity
LS_ITEM_DATA-FACT_UNIT_NOM = <FS_LIPS>-UMVKZ.
LS_ITEM_DATA-FACT_UNIT_DENOM = <FS_LIPS>-UMVKN.
LS_ITEM_DATA-CONV_FACT = <FS_LIPS>-UMREF.
LS_ITEM_DATA-GROSS_WT = <FS_LIPS>-BRGEW.
LS_ITEM_DATA-NET_WEIGHT = <FS_LIPS>-NTGEW.
LS_ITEM_DATA-UNIT_OF_WT = <FS_LIPS>-GEWEI.
LS_ITEM_DATA-VOLUMEUNIT = <FS_LIPS>-VOLEH.
LS_ITEM_DATA-SALES_UNIT = <FS_LIPS>-VRKME.
LS_ITEM_DATA-BASE_UOM = <FS_LIPS>-MEINS.
LS_ITEM_DATA-STOCK_TYPE = <FS_LIPS>-INSMK.
LS_ITEM_DATA-VAL_TYPE = <FS_LIPS>-BWTAR.
LS_ITEM_DATA-INSPLOT = <FS_LIPS>-QPLOS.
LS_ITEM_DATA-VOLUME = <FS_LIPS>-VOLUM.

APPEND LS_ITEM_DATA TO LT_ITEM_DATA.

LS_ITEM_CONTROL-DELIV_NUMB = <FS_LIPS>-VBELN.
LS_ITEM_CONTROL-DELIV_ITEM = <FS_LIPS>-POSNR.
LS_ITEM_CONTROL-CHG_DELQTY = 'X'.

APPEND LS_ITEM_CONTROL TO LT_ITEM_CONTROL.
```