# problem during updating standard table lips-lfimg using FM ws_delivery_update

Tags: abap, sap-erp

My program is to update the standard table after some logic, all the flow seen okay, but the updating process fail and I not sure what happen and what have to change to let the data update at the field of the standard table lips. Any suggestion on it?

Error message log in LT_PROT
[LT_PROT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYsqX.png)

It also shown that there have EF_ERROR_IN_INTERFACE_0 interface error, what needed to check if this error happen?
[error ef](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXTTn.png)

The following is my original code:

```
SELECT * FROM LIPS INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE LT_LIPS
      WHERE VGBEL = LT_BCODE_I-VGBEL
      AND VGPOS = LT_BCODE_I-VGPOS. 
LOOP AT LT_LIPS INTO WA_LIPS.
              WA_LIPS-LFIMG = LT_BCODE_I-MENGE.
              MODIFY LT_LIPS FROM WA_LIPS INDEX SY-TABIX.
            ENDLOOP.

             "VBPOK IS CHANGE INDICATOR, AFTERWARD CALL FUNCTION TO CHANGE FIELD LFIMG IN STANDART TABLE LIPS.
             LOOP AT LT_LIPS INTO GT_LIPS.
               LT_VBPOK-LFIMG = GT_LIPS-LFIMG.
               APPEND LT_VBPOK.
             ENDLOOP.
            ls_vbkok-vbeln_vl   = LT_BCODE_I-REF_DOC.
            CALL FUNCTION 'WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE'
              EXPORTING
                vbkok_wa                    = ls_vbkok    " DELIVERY DOCUMENT NUMBER
                synchron                    = 'X'
                no_messages_update          = ' '
                update_picking              = 'X'
                commit                      = 'X'
                delivery                    = LT_BCODE_I-REF_DOC   "VARIABLE OF DELIVERY DOCUMENT
                nicht_sperren               = 'X'
                if_error_messages_send_0    = space
              IMPORTING
                ef_error_any_0              = ef_error_any_0
                ef_error_in_item_deletion_0 = ef_error_in_item_deletion_0
                ef_error_in_pod_update_0    = ef_error_in_pod_update_0
                ef_error_in_interface_0     = ef_error_in_interface_0
                ef_error_in_goods_issue_0   = ef_error_in_goods_issue_0
                ef_error_in_final_check_0   = ef_error_in_final_check_0
              TABLES
                vbpok_tab                   = lt_vbpok     "TABLE TO BE CHANGE
                prot                        = lt_prot.
```

Comment: no problem not fixed @JózsefSzikszai

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude erm okay

Comment: @NGSUITYAN that comment was placed automatically by stackoverflow, when I marked the question as duplicate. In any case, you asked the same question twice.

Comment: Could you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027720/update-delivery-quantity-via-bapi)?  Same problem was solved via Bapi before.

Comment: You're welcome. If you can solve it just update question with your solution.